# Undefined function or variable vector

Tags: matlab, variables, for-loop, if-statement, vector

I'm using matlab and I have loaded a file that contains the variables date, pH and pressure_dbar (all vectors). I'm trying to write a function that will take in these variables, as well as the maximum and minimum pressure_dbar variables and return two new vectors: newDate and newpH. I want to populate the new vectors with the date and pH data if the date and pH is >= the minimum and < the maximum. Below is my code, but I am getting the error "undefined function or variable" on newDate and newpH. I tried defining them outside of the variable with newDate = []; and newpH = []; but that was also unsuccessful. I also tried different ways of iterating through the vector, but also nothing. Any tips would be appreciated, thanks!

```
minimum = min(pressure_dbar);
maximum = max(pressure_dbar);

function [newDate, newpH] = oceanpHdepth(date, pH, pressure_dbar, minimum, maximum)

for i = 1:length(date)
    for j = 1:length(pH)
        if (ge(pressure_dbar, minimum) && lt(pressure_dbar, maximum))
                newDate = date(i);
                newpH = pH(j);     
        end
    end
end

end
```

Comment: The condition `(ge(pressure_dbar, minimum) && lt(pressure_dbar, maximum))` must never be true

Comment: @Suever I initially had it as (pressure_dbar >= minimum) && (pressure_dbar < maximum) but had the same issue with that. Should I revert back to that anyway and fix the next issue from there? I also tried it with nested if statements, but again didn't get anything different  :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is likely due to the inside of the loop never being reached, and therefore `newDate` and `newpH` are never actually defined inside of the function. This is happening because your aren't actually using the `i` and `j` indices to access a *single element* of `pressure_dbar` and instead you are comparing the entire array every time which is bound to have *some* `false` values and the `if` statement will then always evaluate to false.

Really, it should be

```
if (ge(pressure_dbar(i), minimum) && lt(pressure_dbar(i), maximum))
```

Also, you aren't storing the results of the internal loop into an array at all since you overwrite the values for `newpH` and `newDate` every time. Second, you're better off just using logical indexing to generate `newDate` and `newPH`

```
function [newDate, newpH] = oceanpHdepth(date, pH, pressure_dbar, minimum, maximum)
    mask = pressure_dbar >= minimum & pressure_dbar < maximum;
    newDate = date(mask);
    newpH = pH(mask);
end
```

Comment: This is actually awesome, I've never used a mask before. But I actually want to do it so that its when both the date and the corresponding pH value are within the minimum and maximum. At the moment, that just prints out the same amount of values as my initial vectors. 
Is there a way to do them simultaneously?

Comment: @btoohey Well in your initial code you were comparing `pressure_dbar` for some reason. I'll update it with the code you mention

Comment: Well I do want to compare it. Sorry I haven't explained this well. Your code to me seems like it should work for what I want, but it doesn't actually cut any of the values out of the initial vectors. I just want the date and pH data from the vectors transferred into a new vector when the corresponding pressure_dbar value is within the minimum and maximum, which is what your code did. So I'm unsure of the issue. Thanks so much for the response but.

Comment: Right so I'll revert it then, the issue is that all `pressure_dbar` must be within the range.